# Remote Desktop copying files from Win10 to Server2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, copying

I'm logging in to a Windows Server 2012R2 via Remote Desktop from a Windows 10 pc.
I copy/paste files from the Windows 10 pc to the Windows Server 2012R2.
While doing copy paste I see that the connection quickly disconnects and reconnects resulting in a failed copy/paste.

The error message:

```
Error Copying File or Folder
Unspecified error
```

Nothing is logged in the windows event viewer.

If I copy big files or many files (together > 2MB) I always get this quick disconnect and the copy/paste fails. when I only copy small amounts < 2MB (or if lucky 1 file of 4 or 7MB) the copy/paste is successful.

any advice?

(The server is not added in a domain.)

Comment: Are you connected over UDP or TCP? When you are connected to your server via UDP then your server have internet problems or you have some. Try to upload the files to mediafire or something else and download the file from there. That should be no problem when you only open the download link in the server.

Comment: it is by simply using the remte desktop connection application over local network, I don't know if this uses UDP or TCP... with other server(s) I don't have this copy/paste problem.

Comment: I get this all the time. Sometimes it works, sometimes I have to run multiple times before it copies successfully

Comment: I am having the same issue. But it seems client related. Other clients dont have this issue.

Comment: the "other clients" are they the same OS?

Comment: @AndrewRimmer did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

known bug, use share or drive or usb key

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2258090/copying-files-larger-than-2-gb-over-a-remote-desktop-services-or-terminal-services-session-by-using-clipboard-redirection-copy-and-paste-fails-silently

Comment: it s not with big files, also a bunch of small files.